# UISlider Not displaying the Tract

Tags: ios, swift

I created a block to add UISlider programmatically to have total control of the design. How ever it displays on the thumb image without showing the tract. I will appreciate if anyone could help me resolve the problem.
thank you.

```
    let ageSlider: UISlider = {
    let ageS = UISlider(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 300, height: 20))
    ageS.minimumValue = 0
    ageS.maximumValue = 60
    ageS.value = 24
    ageS.tintColor = .green
    ageS.isContinuous = true
    print("creating age slider")
    //ageS.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.trackStrokeColor
    //ageS.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.pulsatingFillColor
    ageS.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return ageS
}()
```

[image]

Comment: You are setting a frame for your slider, but then setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` --- which (essentially) removes the frame. Are you somewhere setting auto-layout constraints on you `ageSlider` object (after adding it as a subview)? If so, show that code... If not, that's what you need.

Comment: Am setting auto-layout constraints on my ageSlider.

Comment: OK - you need to show the constraints you are setting.

Comment: // add age slider constraints to age view. ageView is the container of the ageSlider
        ageSlider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ageView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        ageSlider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

Comment: You don't see the "track" because you are not giving the slider a Width constraint.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. It's showing now after adding the width constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a width constraint to your slider object:

```
    // add age slider constraints to age view. ageView is the container of the ageSlider

    // center ageSlider both horizontally and vertically
    ageSlider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ageView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    ageSlider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    // constrain ageSlider width to 90% of ageView width
    ageSlider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco) to `false` if you want to manually set the `frame` of the UI component.

Either set it to true:

```
ageS.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

or just comment that line.

If you want the size to not be static, and change when the phone orientation changes, or when the frame of the superview changes, ..., then use constraints. In your case, you are missing the width constraint.